# WPF: even if UpdateSourceTrigger == Explicit, source value is changed when binding is set

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, updatesourcetrigger

I have a simple `Window`

```
<Window x:Class="BindingProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="mainWnd">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Simple, ElementName=mainWnd, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
</Window>
```

with a custom `DependencyProperty` named *Simple*

```
public static DependencyProperty SimpleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Simple", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata("initial", SimpleChanged));
private static void SimpleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Simple changed from \"{0}\" to \"{1}\"", e.OldValue.ToString(), e.NewValue.ToString()));
}
public string Simple
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(SimpleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SimpleProperty, value); }
}
```

the problem is that when the binding is set for the first time at the startup of the application, source (the value of *Simple* property) is updated even without calling `UpdateSource` and I see the `MessageBox` with the following message: *Simple changed from "initial" to ""*.

How can I get rid of such behaviour?

Comment: Check for `e.OldValue` if it is null. If it is then don't do anything. Else update the `SimpleProperty`

Comment: @lll Do you mean `e.NewValue`?

Comment: Same just happened to me. I really don't understand why it behaves in that way. Did you find any solution for this @undermind ?

Comment: @T.Y.Kucuk It seems that the _OneWayToSource_ mode triggers the source update when the binding is being attached. [Look](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpression.cs,1008), the `initialTransferIsUpdate` variable is set to `true` in such case, and in the line 1034 source update is called.
I don't remember what workaround I've implemented, but you can, for example, undo the very first change of the source property (because you know that it's called by the binding attachment, not by the user actions).